# Jquery unable to parse jsonp dataType response when there is no space before the value

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, cross-domain, jsonp

The jquery ajax response handler seems to fail when it can't find a space prefixed to the value. This ajax respose fails

```
{"ip":"bla"}
```

This passes

```
{"ip": "bla"}
```

Here is the simplified version of code that I'm trying

```
<html lang="en">
<body>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "https://api.myjson.com/bins/4as0v",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function (data) {

        alert('Success call back called')
        }
    })
</script>
Hi 

</body>
</html>
```

And below is the error that I'm getting

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

Now, I have tried changing the dataType in $.ajax to text and manually parsing the text in the callback to json and that works.

```
dataType: 'jsonp',
```

...

```
success: function (data) {
    data = JSON.parse(data);    
    }
```

However in my actual application i will need to make a cross domain request and hence forced to use jsonp dataType. I have also tried multiple, space-separated values (as of Jquery 1.5) to try interpreting jsonp as text with no success.

Note that the ReponseHeader of the url that i intend to access data from does not have Access-Control-Allow-Origin property set to *

Any hint/suggestion is deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your code is requesting a json url not jsonp. a jsonp should have a callback function to work. Please read this for jsonp http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

for your example to work you can use $.getJSON to read json.

```
$.getJSON('https://api.myjson.com/bins/4as0v', function(data){
        alert('Success call back called \n'+data.ip)
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick resposne. The code snippet that u mentioned works as the json url (https://api.myjson.com/bins/4as0v) has "Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*" as one of the ResponseHeader attributes. But the url that i intend to use in my application doesn't have that set. Hence the need for jsonp.

Comment: to use the url as jsonp there should be callback function, thats mean the response format should looks like callbackFunc({"ip": "bla"})

Comment: here is a sample code for your code how it should looks like, but sure will not work because your url not jsonp. http://jsfiddle.net/La8w4b1q/

Comment: ahh, thanks. I see that there's a jsonp endpoint as well. Will verify and mark ur answer :D